# Grails 3 - Marshaller with XML

Tags: xml, grails, marshalling, grails-3.1

I have grails 3.1 application.

Below is the code for customizing the elements, which uses JSON marshaller, which works perfectly.

```
JSON.createNamedConfig("memeListView", {
            JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Meme) { Meme memeIns ->
                return [
                        caption: memeIns.caption,
                        likeCount: memeIns.likeCount,
                ]
            }
        })
```

But, I have tried the above code for XML marshaller, but it displays entire object attributes, instead of required. Below is the code for XML marshalling.

```
XML.createNamedConfig("memeListView", {
                XML.registerObjectMarshaller(Meme) { Meme memeIns ->
                    return [
                            caption: memeIns.caption,
                            likeCount: memeIns.likeCount,
                    ]
                }
            })
```

In action part

```
JSON.use('memeListView'){
      render memesList as JSON
}
```

Kindly suggest me, how to do marshalling for xml response.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you have to return something XML-ish.  I think the xml marshaller passes in a 2nd arg.

So maybe (trying this from memory):

```
XML.createNamedConfig("memeListView", {
    it.registerObjectMarshaller(Meme) { Meme memeIns, xml ->
        xml.build {
            caption(memeIns.caption )
            likeCount( memeIns.likeCount )
        }
    }
})
```

or

```
XML.createNamedConfig("memeListView", {
    it.registerObjectMarshaller(Meme) { Meme memeIns, xml ->
        xml.attribute 'caption', memeIns.caption
        xml.attribute 'likeCount', memIns.likeCount
    }
})
```

depending on how you want the XML to look?

Comment: XML.use("memeListView") {

            render memeList as XML
        }

Comment: try it again?  Notice I changed to "it.registerObjectMarshaller" from "XML.registerObejctMarshaller".  Also... add a breakpoint to see if the marshaller code is actually being used?

Comment: Glad it worked...  If we're done here, go ahead and click the check-mark so others know you found what you were looking for.